# Can the EM algorithm be used to perform model selection?

Tags: model-selection, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution

Suppose that the samples $\mathcal{D} = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N\}$ were independently sampled from a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. However, suppose that we did not know beforehand that the samples in $\mathcal{D}$ were Gaussian distributed, and that we were only presented with these samples. One way I thought about determining which distribution these samples were independently and identically sampled from is as follows:

1. Setup a mixture model consisting of $K$ different distributions as components. For example, for $K = 3$, the mixture could consist of a Gaussian distribution, a Laplace distribution, and an exponential distribution.
2. Estimate the parameters of this mixture model, including the component probabilities, using the EM algorithm.
3. Form $K$ different likelihood functions using each component. For example, if the components are Gaussian, Laplace, and exponential, then form one likelihood function as a product of identical Gaussian distributions with the estimated parameters, another likelihood function as a product of identical Laplace distributions with the estimated parameters, and another likelihood function as a product of identical exponential distributions with the estimated parameters.
4. Input the samples in $\mathcal{D}$ into each of the $K$ likelihood functions, and then choose the distribution that returns the highest likelihood.

Are there any flaws with this method? If not, does this method have a name?

Comment: This is a neat idea. Each of the $K$ components will fit (to some extent) the distribution of the subset of the sample allocated to this component. But not necessarily the entire sample. In order to avoid overfitting, I would try to compare the likelihoods of the out-of-cluster sample, that is using for eg the Normal likelihood the observations not-much-allocated to the Normal component. Without any warranty!

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for the feedback! Do you have any papers/books in mind that discuss this idea or something similar?

Comment: No, not at all. Maybe a connection with leave-one-out methods.